# Laravel Eloquent - having problems updating JSON col in PostgreSQL

Tags: php, json, postgresql, eloquent, jsonb

**Part 1: Main Question**

On my `colours_tab` table (PostgreSQL 9.6), I have a column called `colours_json_col` of type JSONB.
I have the following code in my Laravel controller which creates a new record on the afore-mentioned table:

```
$colour_rec = new ColoursModel();
$colour_rec -> colours_json_col = ['fruits' => ['apple' => 'pink'] ];
$colour_rec -> update (['colours_json_col->fruits->apple' => 'green']);
$colour_rec -> saveOrFail();
```

The above code doesn't error or throw an exception, yet after executing it the new record in my database contains the following JSON data:

```
{"fruits": {"apple": "pink"}}
```

Obviously, what I want is for the apple to be green, not pink!  The documentation here (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#updates) suggests that I'm doing the right thing in order set it 'green'.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

**Part 2: Bonus Question**

In order to prevent the above code from erroring, I have had to declare the column `colours_json_col` as `$fillable` in the model:

```
protected $fillable = ['colours_json_col'];
```

I don't really want to set the column as `$fillable` if at all possible.  Therefore, is there a way to update the value without having to call the `update()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering both parts of the question in one:

```
$colour_rec = new ColoursModel();
$colour_rec -> colours_json_col = ['fruits' => ['apple' => 'pink'] ];
$colour_rec -> setAttribute ('colours_json_col->fruits->apple', 'green');
$colour_rec -> saveOrFail();
```

It seems to be an undocumented feature in Eloquent, as far as I can tell.